# Memory error when using Keras ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am attempting to predict features in imagery using keras with a TensorFlow backend. Specifically, I am attempting to use a keras [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). The model is set to run for 4 epochs and runs fine until the 4th epoch where it fails with a MemoryError.

I am running this model on an AWS [g2.2xlarge](https://www.ec2instances.info/?selected=g2.2xlarge) instance running Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type.

The training images are 256x256 RGB pixel tiles (8 bit unsigned) and the training mask is 256x256 single band (8 bit unsigned) tiled data where 255 == a feature of interest and 0 == everything else.

The following 3 functions are the ones pertinent to this error.

How can I resolve this MemoryError?

---

```
def train_model():
        batch_size = 1
        training_imgs = np.lib.format.open_memmap(filename=os.path.join(data_path, 'data.npy'),mode='r+')
        training_masks = np.lib.format.open_memmap(filename=os.path.join(data_path, 'mask.npy'),mode='r+')
        dl_model = create_model()
        print(dl_model.summary())
        model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(data_path,'mod_weight.hdf5'), monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
        dl_model.fit_generator(generator(training_imgs, training_masks, batch_size), steps_per_epoch=(len(training_imgs)/batch_size), epochs=4,verbose=1,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])

def generator(train_imgs, train_masks=None, batch_size=None):

# Create empty arrays to contain batch of features and labels#

        if train_masks is not None:
                train_imgs_batch = np.zeros((batch_size,y_to_res,x_to_res,bands))
                train_masks_batch = np.zeros((batch_size,y_to_res,x_to_res,1))

                while True:
                        for i in range(batch_size):
                                # choose random index in features
                                index= random.choice(range(len(train_imgs)))
                                train_imgs_batch[i] = train_imgs[index]
                                train_masks_batch[i] = train_masks[index]
                        yield train_imgs_batch, train_masks_batch
        else:
                rec_imgs_batch = np.zeros((batch_size,y_to_res,x_to_res,bands))
                while True:
                        for i in range(batch_size):
                                # choose random index in features
                                index= random.choice(range(len(train_imgs)))
                                rec_imgs_batch[i] = train_imgs[index]
                        yield rec_imgs_batch

def train_generator(train_images,train_masks,batch_size):
        data_gen_args=dict(rotation_range=90.,horizontal_flip=True,vertical_flip=True,rescale=1./255)
        image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
        mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
# # Provide the same seed and keyword arguments to the fit and flow methods
        seed = 1
        image_datagen.fit(train_images, augment=True, seed=seed)
        mask_datagen.fit(train_masks, augment=True, seed=seed)
        image_generator = image_datagen.flow(train_images,batch_size=batch_size)
        mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow(train_masks,batch_size=batch_size)
        return zip(image_generator, mask_generator)
```

---

The following os the output from the model detailing the epochs and the error message:

```
Epoch 00001: loss improved from inf to 0.01683, saving model to /home/ubuntu/deep_learn/client_data/mod_weight.hdf5
Epoch 2/4
7569/7569 [==============================] - 3394s 448ms/step - loss: 0.0049 - binary_crossentropy: 0.0027 - jaccard_coef_int: 0.9983  

Epoch 00002: loss improved from 0.01683 to 0.00492, saving model to /home/ubuntu/deep_learn/client_data/mod_weight.hdf5
Epoch 3/4
7569/7569 [==============================] - 3394s 448ms/step - loss: 0.0049 - binary_crossentropy: 0.0026 - jaccard_coef_int: 0.9982  

Epoch 00003: loss improved from 0.00492 to 0.00488, saving model to /home/ubuntu/deep_learn/client_data/mod_weight.hdf5
Epoch 4/4
7569/7569 [==============================] - 3394s 448ms/step - loss: 0.0074 - binary_crossentropy: 0.0042 - jaccard_coef_int: 0.9975  

Epoch 00004: loss did not improve
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_rec.py", line 291, in <module>
    train_model()
  File "image_rec.py", line 208, in train_model
    dl_model.fit_generator(train_generator(training_imgs,training_masks,batch_size),steps_per_epoch=1,epochs=1,workers=1)
  File "image_rec.py", line 274, in train_generator
    image_datagen.fit(train_images, augment=True, seed=seed)
  File "/home/ubuntu/pyvirt_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 753, in fit
    x = np.copy(x)
  File "/home/ubuntu/pyvirt_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1505, in copy
    return array(a, order=order, copy=True)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Can you clean your code up by chance? You have sections of code commented out, and the error appears to reference code that's not in your included snippet (I don't see a call to `train_generator` anywhere in your code, but that's the error location). It may be hard to debug with what you've provided.

Comment: Does it always happen at 4th epoch even if you change random seed? I saw your batch size is 1, so each time it fit only 1 image to train, can it be a problem with one of your image that is very large size and np.copy() cause memory error?

Comment: @BinhNguyenLe It still has a memory error with less epochs. I haven't tried changing the random seed.

Comment: Have you considered updating tensorflow and keras?

Answer (score 11):

it seems your problem is due to the data is too huge. I can see two solutions. The first one is run your code in a distributed system by means of spark, I guess you do not have this support, so let us move on to the other.

The second one is which I think is viable. I would slice the data and I would try feeding the model incrementally. We can do this with **Dask**. This library can slice the data and save in objects which then you can retrieve reading from disk, only in the part you want.

If you have a image which size is an matrix of 100x100, we can retrieve each array without the needed to load the 100 arrays in memory. We can load array by array in memory (releasing the previous one), which would be the input in your Neural Network.

To do this, you can to transform your np.array to dask array and assign the partitions. For example:

```
>>> k = np.random.randn(10,10) # Matrix 10x10
>>> import dask.array as da
>>> k2 = da.from_array(k,chunks = 3)
dask.array<array, shape=(10, 10), dtype=float64, chunksize=(3, 3)>
>>> k2.to_delayed()
array([[Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 0, 0)),
    Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 0, 1)),
    Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 0, 2)),
    Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 0, 3))],
   [Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 1, 0)),
    Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 1, 1)),
    Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 1, 2)),
    Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 1, 3))],
   [Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 2, 0)),
    Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 2, 1)),
    Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 2, 2)),
    Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 2, 3))],
   [Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 3, 0)),
    Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 3, 1)),
    Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 3, 2)),
    Delayed(('array-a08c1d25b900d497cdcd233a7c5aa108', 3, 3))]],
  dtype=object)
```

Here, you can see how the data is saved in objects, and then you can retrieve in parts to feed your model.

To implement this solution you must introduce a loop in your function which call each partition and feed the NN to get the incremental trainning.

For more information, see **Dask** documentation

Comment: @Borealis Try it! this method is very useful to divide part or train high amount of data

Comment: I liked this idea but how to retrieve them in part.. I was reading the documentation but got more doubts than anything..

Comment: @MarlonTeixeira Then, you can set an iterator (yield instead of return in your function). The method to retrieve the chunk is:  da.from_delayed("chunk that you want to get", shape...), and then you have to do .compute() or persist() to retrieve in memory.

Comment: I could ran your idea but unfortunately, I'm still having the memory error.  I have already tried many things... maybe I'll have to split the file, which I take as defeat...

Comment: @MarlonTeixeira You can try doing chuncks smaller. You can get this from a dask-dataframe with a blocksize smaller or applying ddf.repartition(npartitions=...)

Comment: Julio, I appreciate very much your comment. The question in the link below has been made by the guy that works with me. If you want to answer it we would thank you so much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63603076/how-to-feed-a-conv2d-net-with-a-large-npy-file-without-overhelming-the-ram-memor

Answer (score 7):

You provided quite confusing code (in my opinion), ie. no call to the `train_generator` is visible. I am not sure that this is a problem of insufficient memore due to a big data, since you use memmap for that, but lets assume for now it is.

- If the data is quite big and since you're loading the images from directory anyway, it might be worthy considering to use `ImageDataGenerator`'s `flow_from_directory` method.
  It would require a slight change of design, tho, which might not be what you want.

You can load it in the following manner:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(256, 256),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        ...  # other configurations)
```

More on that [in the Keras documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).

- Also note that if you have 32bit, the `memmap` does not allow more than 2GB.
- Do you use `tensorflow-gpu`, by any chance? Maybe your gpu is not sufficient, you could try this with the `tensorflow` package.

I would strongly suggest to try some [memory profiling](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) to see where bigger allocations of memory happen.

---

If it was not the case of insufficient memory, It might be wrong handling of the data in your model, since your loss function is not improving at all, it could be miswired for example.

---

Finally, the last note here .. it is good practice to load the memmap of training data as `read-only`, since you don't want to accidentaly mess the data.

**UPDATE**: I can see that you've updated the post and provided the code for the `train_generator` method, but there is still no call to that method in your call.

If I assume that you have a typo in the call - `train_generator` instead of the `generator` method in your `d1_model.fit_generator` method, it is possible that the `fit_generator` method is not working on a batch of data, but actually on the whole `training_imgs` and it copys over the whole set in the `np.copy(x)` call.

Also, as mentioned already, there indeed are (you can find some of them, fe. [here is an open one](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8668)) a few issues with Keras memory leak when using the `fit` and `fit_generator` methods.

Answer (score 4):

This is common when running 32bit if the float precision is too high. Are you running 32bit? You may also consider casting or rounding the array.

Comment: I'm running 8bit unsigned imagery and training data.

Comment: Have you inspected the data to ensure it retains the 8bit precision? I ran in to this problem recently and the data would at times get a much higher precision than specified. I had to explicitly round the array after updating weights.

Answer (score 4):

Generally Keras/Tensorflow is very good with resource usage, but there is a known memory leak that has caused problems in the past. To make sure that's not the one causing your problems, try including these two lines of code to your training script:

```
# load the backend
from keras import backend as K

# prevent Tensorflow memory leakage
K.clear_session()
```

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem recently. Somehow the the FCN-8 code can run successfully on my tensorflow1.2+keras2.0.9+8G RAM +1060 computer, but occurred memory error when using modelcheckpoint on my tf1.4+keras2.1.5+16g ram +1080ti computer.